# Check versions used inside a FatJar/ShadowJar

Tags: java, dependencies, version, shadowjar

so since the log4j-issue hit pretty far and wide, I was wondering how to determine the currently used version inside a shadowjar.

I'm creating one fat jar using `com.github.jengelman`'s shadow v5.2 and was not able to figure out which version of log4j or any other classes from multiple .jars (poi, saxon, junit) was used. Of course I have the original .jar's the fat jar is made from, but still I was wondering if there is a way to either display the dependencies that are packed into the shadow jar, or if there is a way to determine their version when the full jar is finished.

So far I couldn't find any way to see inside the jar which version of a class is used, and unfortunately there also seems to be no way to list all the versions while packing the jar.

The actual reason to check the versions is a log4j inside the shadow-folder of the shadow jar. So before I do some byte-diff of the .class-file against the original jar, I was hoping for a nicer solution that might be logging them in the build process, so is there any other way to see what dependecies with which versions went inside it?